# How to prove union and intersection of classes if sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Im working on some book exercises and struggle with a proof.

If $B_i$ and $C_j$ are two classes of sets such that $B_i \subseteq  C_j $.
How can I show that $\bigcup\limits_i B_{i}  \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{j} C_{j}$ and $\bigcap\limits_j C_{j} \subseteq \bigcap\limits_{i} B_{i}$

So far I have tried for $\bigcup\limits_i B_{i}  \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{j} C_{j}$:

Let $x  \in \bigcup\limits_i B_{i} \subseteq \bigcup\limits_j C_{j} \iff x \in B_i \cup C_j$

By the definition of union, it follows that $x \in B_i$ or  $x \in C_j$

By definition of subset it follows that $x \in B_i \implies x \in C_j$

So far I have tried for $\bigcap\limits_j C_{j} \subseteq \bigcap\limits_{i} B_{i}$:

Take any subset $x \subseteq B_i \cap C_j$.

$x \subseteq B_i \wedge x \subseteq C_j$, meaning that $x \in \bigcup\limits_i B_{i} \wedge x \in \bigcup\limits_j C_{j}$.

However not sure whether that is correct. Appreciate any help.

Comment: "So far I have for the union:" [not-well-written string of symbols that looks like a false statement]

Comment: I think all ingredients are assembled :), there is really not much to add. Maybe $B_i \subset \bigcup\limits_{j} B_j$

Comment: Hello, thank you both for taking time reviewing my question. However, I cant really take anything away from both comments. Do you mean thats wrong or is it not much to add because its correct?

Comment: I don't think you have given all the information correctly.  This isn't true.

Comment: You miswrote the problem.

Comment: @fleablood I apologize for causing misunderstanding. But what exactly do you mean by miswrote?

Comment: I mean you miswrote.  $B_i \subset C_j$ was not a given condition.  $\{B_i\} \subset \{C_j\}$ was the given condition.  What your wrote was every set $B_i$ is a subset of all $C_j$.  What Simmons wrote was that the *set* of all $B_i$ was a subset of the *set* of all $C_i$.  That's a *VERY* different condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misstated the problem for  Simmons Introduction to Topology and Analysis.

The problem was:

Let $\{A_i\}, \{B_j\}$ be to classes of sets. so that $\{A_i\} \subset \{B_i\}$ (in other words it is the **classes** of sets that are subsets of each other and **NOT** the individual sets)

Now show that $\cup_i A_i \subset \cup_j B_j$ and $\cap B_j \subset \cap_i A_i$.

Again, my advice is element chase:

Let $x \cup_i A_i$ then $x \in A_i$ for some $A_i$.  Now $\{A_i\} \subset \{B_i\}$ so $A_i = B_k$ for some $B_k \in \{B_j\}$ so $x \in B_k$. so $x \in \cup_j B_j$.

So $\cup_i A_i \subset \cup_j B_j$.

If $x \in \cap_j B_j$ then $x \in B_j$ for *all* the $B_j$.  Let $A_i$ be any set in $\{A_i\} \subset \{B_j\}$.  Then $A_i = B_k$ for $B_k \in \{B_j\}$.  So $x \in B_k = A_i$ because $x$ is in *all* $B_j$.  Thus it is in all the $A_i \in \{A_i\} \subset \{B_j\}$ so it is in $\cap_i A_i$.

$\cap B_j \subset \cap_i A_i$.

Comment: Hi @fleablood, thank you for the answer. However "I think you meant" its not true. I really meant C subset B. Its an excersie from Intro to Topology and modern Analysis page 13. 1.

Comment: You have edited the page since I wrote this answer.  You first wrote $B_i \subset C_i$.  If that is all you know, I am correct ($i = i$).  But in your new edit you have $B_i \subset C_j$ meaning *ANY* $B_i$ is a subset of *ANY* $C_j$.  That is an *ENTIRELY* different situation.

Comment: Im sorry, I have realized that when you have pointed out the apparent mistake.

Comment: Actually, I think you must have copied the question incompletely/incorrectly.

Comment: Okay, I see the error you made.  I will redo this.

Answer (score 0):

For $\bigcup_i B_i \subseteq \bigcup_i C_i$, take an element $x \in B_i \subseteq C_i$. We then conclude $\bigcup_i B_i \subseteq \bigcup_i C_i$, because $x \in B_i \subseteq \bigcup_i B_i$ and because for all $i$, $B_i \subseteq C_i$, we have $x \in B_i \subseteq C_i \subseteq \bigcup_i C_i$.

For $\bigcap_i C_i \subseteq \bigcap B_i$, use element-chasing again by taking an element in all $C_i$, that is, an element in $\bigcap_i C_i$, than it is in all $B_i$, that is, an element in $\bigcap_i B_i$, because $B_i \subseteq C_i$ for all $i$. A hint: look at the complements of $B_i$ and $C_i$ for all $i$.

Make sure you state well from which set you are taking an arbitrary element. Show that that arbitrary element is also in the second set and you have proven the set inclusion.

Comment: Why would an element in all the $C_i$ be in all $B_i$?  The $C_i$ are not subsets of $B_i$.  Suppose $x$ is in all $C_i$ but $x$ is in none of the $B_i$ (or there is at least one $B_i$ that doesn't contain $x$).  Then this would be simply false.  Example.  $C_i = [0, i]$ and $B_i = [10-i, 10]$.  Then all $x: 0 \le x \le 1$ are in all $C_i$ but are not in  $B_1, B_2,... B_8$.